# failed : Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK

Tags: unity-game-engine

im trying now to upload game as apkfile built by unity 3d to google play store for testing but unfortunately im facing error from google "your instant app apks should contain at least one base apk."

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to upload it as an instant app?

Comment: the Reason , its the first time im doing that ... from your answer  it seem im uploding the apk in wrong place  ? the step still not clear to me as i understand

Comment: im using Google Play 2017 - New Google interface and it seem i should upload it as  instant app

Comment: its solved the issue  i should uplad the apk file in the app release not instant app